# PHP elapsed execution time on different server

Tags: php, codeigniter, execution-time

I am using codeigniter for benchmarking use `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE)` . On development server, I got ~0.17 second, but on production server it extremely slow, I got ~6 second. Same code, same php version, same apache and mysql version. Whet else I need to check ? **What things needs to be checked if PHP execution time is too slow ?**. Thanks.

Comment: Hardware specs might be different.

Comment: Hardware, network, virtualisation software, etc.

Comment: are the `php.ini` and Apache's `http.conf` settings are same?

Comment: Is php running as an apache module or via cgi? Also check if you are using a cache module to speed up execution (apc/eaccelerator) on your development server.